# how to fix brensenham's circle algorithm's circle gaps

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm working on 2D Graphics Engine. Bits are the final output of the 32bit bitmaps bytes. I examined the code on the debugger , the values are correct but there are always gaps.
I use the following function to compose the circle but on the 2nd quadrant there are gaps on the circle.
How can I fix it? What am I doin' wrong here?

```
bool Graphics::Circle::compose(void)
{
    BYTE* bits{ nullptr };

    try {
        if (mRadius <= 0) {
            throw Error::Exception(L"Çember çapı doğru değil", L"Çember Oluşturma Hatası");
        }

        Pixel outlineColor = App->GetRenderer()->getCurrentOutlineColor();

        mWidth  = 2 * mRadius;
        mHeight = 2 * mRadius;

        bits = new BYTE[mWidth * mHeight * 4]{ 0 };
        int x{ 0 }, y{ mRadius };
        std::array<int, 8> indices{ 0 };
        int decision{ 3 - 2 * mRadius };
        do {
            if (decision > 0) {
                --y;
                decision += 4 * (x - y) + 10;
            } else {
                decision += 4 * x + 6;
            }

            indices[0] = (mRadius - y) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius + x) * 4);
            indices[1] = (mRadius - y) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius - x) * 4);
            indices[2] = (mRadius + y) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius + x) * 4);
            indices[3] = (mRadius + y) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius - x) * 4);
            indices[4] = (mRadius + x) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius - y) * 4);
            indices[5] = (mRadius + x) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius + y) * 4);
            indices[6] = (mRadius - x) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius - y) * 4);
            indices[7] = (mRadius - x) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius + y) * 4);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i) {
                bits[indices[i] + 0] = outlineColor.mBlue;
                bits[indices[i] + 1] = outlineColor.mGreen;
                bits[indices[i] + 2] = outlineColor.mRed;
                bits[indices[i] + 3] = outlineColor.mAlpha;

            }   
        } while (++x <= y);

        if (setBits(bits, mWidth, mHeight)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            throw Error::Exception(L"Çember bitleri oluşturulamadı", L"Çember Oluşturma Hatası");
        }
    } catch (Error::Exception& ex) {
        if (bits) {
            delete[] bits;
        }

        Error::ShowError(ex.getErrorMessage(), ex.getErrorTitle());

        return false;
    } catch (std::exception& ex) {
        if (bits) {
            delete[] bits;
        }

        Error::ShowError(ex.what(), L"Çember Oluşturma Hatası");

        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the screenshot :
[image]
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, problem was the canvas was not big enough to contain the circle.
Here is the updated function :

```
bool Graphics::Circle::compose(void)
{
    BYTE* bits{ nullptr };

    try {
        if (mRadius <= 0) {
            throw Error::Exception(L"Çember çapı doğru değil", L"Çember Oluşturma Hatası");
        }

        Pixel outlineColor = App->GetRenderer()->getCurrentOutlineColor();
        Pixel fillColor    = App->GetRenderer()->getCurrentFillColor();

        mWidth  = 2 * mRadius + 1;
        mHeight = 2 * mRadius + 1;

        bits = new BYTE[mWidth * mHeight * 4]{ 0 };
        
        int                x{ 0 }, y{ mRadius };
        std::array<int, 8> indices{ 0 };
        int                decision{ 3 - 2 * mRadius };
        do {
            if (decision > 0) {
                --y;
                decision += 4 * (x - y) + 10;
            } else {
                decision += 4 * x + 6;
            }

            indices[0] = (mRadius - y) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius + x) * 4);
            indices[1] = (mRadius - y) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius - x) * 4);
            indices[2] = (mRadius + y) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius + x) * 4);
            indices[3] = (mRadius + y) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius - x) * 4);
            indices[4] = (mRadius + x) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius - y) * 4);
            indices[5] = (mRadius + x) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius + y) * 4);
            indices[6] = (mRadius - x) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius - y) * 4);
            indices[7] = (mRadius - x) * mWidth * 4 + ((mRadius + y) * 4);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i) {
                bits[indices[i] + 0] = outlineColor.mBlue;
                bits[indices[i] + 1] = outlineColor.mGreen;
                bits[indices[i] + 2] = outlineColor.mRed;
                bits[indices[i] + 3] = outlineColor.mAlpha;

            }
        } while (++x <= y);

        if (mFill) {
            float          distance{ 0.0f };
            Math::Vector2D center{ (float)mWidth / 2.0f, (float)mHeight / 2.0f };
            Math::Vector2D pixel{ 0.0f, 0.0f };
            int            index{ 0 };
            for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; ++j) {
                    pixel.setX((float)j);
                    pixel.setY((float)i);
                    distance = Math::Distance(pixel, center);
                    if (distance < (float)mRadius) {
                        index = i * mWidth * 4 + j * 4;
                        if (bits[index + 0] != outlineColor.mBlue &&
                            bits[index + 1] != outlineColor.mGreen &&
                            bits[index + 2] != outlineColor.mRed &&
                            bits[index + 3] != outlineColor.mAlpha) {
                            bits[index + 0] = fillColor.mBlue;
                            bits[index + 1] = fillColor.mGreen;
                            bits[index + 2] = fillColor.mRed;
                            bits[index + 3] = fillColor.mAlpha;
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }

        if (setBits(bits, mWidth, mHeight)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            throw Error::Exception(L"Çember bitleri oluşturulamadı", L"Çember Oluşturma Hatası");
        }
    } catch (Error::Exception& ex) {
        if (bits) {
            delete[] bits;
        }

        Error::ShowError(ex.getErrorMessage(), ex.getErrorTitle());

        return false;
    } catch (std::exception& ex) {
        if (bits) {
            delete[] bits;
        }

        Error::ShowError(ex.what(), L"Çember Oluşturma Hatası");

        return false;
    }
}
```